SVN Invalid Authz Configuration
My SVN server was recently updated, and now when I try to connect to the repository in eclipse, I receive the below error:
Error validating location: "org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Can't create session
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svnserver/opt/svn/repo/ABC' Invalid authz configuration
svn: Invalid authz configuration

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this and any help is greatly appreciated.

Anyone with suggestions?

The issue was in the authorization file. There were some duplicate entries. Hope this helps someone else.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
